# Logistic regression, Fisher Exact test, or am I just completely off?

Tags: regression

I'm having a hard time determining an appropriate way to analyze a large dataset for a city's street tree inventory. I'm attempting to statistically support if any given species is more likely to produce sidewalk damage. Personally, I am under the impression that the planter size is a much more relevant variable for predicting the likelihood of sidewalk damage.

An example of how the raw data looks:

- Species         | Planter size| SidewalkDamage
- Red maple       |       5     | Present
- Red maple       |       5     | Absent
- Red maple       |       5     | Absent
- Red maple       |       5     | Absent
- Norway Maple    |       4     | Present
- Norway Maple    |       4     | Present
- Norway Maple    |       4     | Absent
- Norway Maple    |       6     | Present

  ... Then This continues on for a 24,000 more measures...

While working with the data in this form it makes the most sense to me to use a logistic regression (Two Independent Variables one categorical the other continuous but readily adapted into a categorical and a binomial response), but from my understanding this doesn't seem like it will work because I have multiple measures for any given species.

My next thought was to try and analyze the data in a summarized form:

An example table:

Instances of sidewalk damage
                          Planter Size

- Species       | 0-4 ft| 4-8 ft| 8-12 ft| 12ft+
- Red Maple     |  30   |    20 | 2      | 8
- Norway Maple  |  58   |    22 | 3      | 0
- Doug Fir      |  6    |    0  | 4      | 0
- Elm           | 12    |    8  | 0      | 1
- Birch         | 0     |    1  | 0      | 0

  ...This continues on for a couple hundred species...

In this form I was thinking about using a Fisher exact test (or whatever permutation of a chi squared is actually most applicable). The issue that I am having with trying to analyze the data in this form is that I'm completely disregarding the measures without instances of sidewalk damage and have null values in any given planter category. These issues potentially lead to species that may have drastically more measures (something like 5000 red maples vs 100 elms sampled) are disproportionately being represented in my analysis and additionally I have just heard anecdotally that having null values in my table is a headache for a lot of statistical analyses.

I'm looking for some guidance of how to proceed from here. I feel like I've been chasing my tail on how to approach this and could definitely use some insight from someone with an actual statistical background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"from my understanding this doesn't seem like it will work because I have multiple measures for any given species".

No, this is typical of logistic regression problems. Use the first approach.

It's not clear in the second approach how you are representing the probability of damage (e.g. Red Maple, 0-4 ft has 30 instances of damage -- out of how many?)

Comment: This unclarity is exactly what I was having trouble with conceptualizing and is leading me to believe that analyzing the data in the manner presented in the second table is moot. Although for clarification, in that example there are 5000 red maples sampled with 60 instances of damage (row total). So conversely there would be 4940 instances without damage, which I was ignoring in that presentation of the data. I think I was trying to make the data fit the test as opposed to finding a test to fit the data. Any other suggested assessments other than logistic regression for this type of data?

Comment: You might want to try a decision tree (C4.5/C5 or rpart in R), mainly to see whether you see an interaction.  For example, it might be that the planter size matters for red maples, but doesn't matter for douglas firs, perhaps due to different root structures (I am NOT an arborist.)  If there's no interaction, I think logistic is the most straightforward way to go here.

Comment: I've successfully used a logistic regression and found that species is not significant predictor of the presence of sidewalk damage. I then proceeded to play with other independent variables to see how predictive they are. I've found that planter size and height are both significant predictors. How would I proceed to try and provide recommendations such as height restrictions for various planter sizes? Or in other words, at what height is sidewalk damage going to occur at a given percent chance?

Comment: Here's what I'd do. Set up a table with planter size groups as columns and height groups as rows.  Use your logistic regression equation to predict the probability of damage in each cell. As a check (and to provide an additional tool for convincing management) tabulate the actual data the same way. This will give you the actual percentages and the smoother, modeled percentages, which should agree fairly well.

Comment: By the way, you might want to accept the answer above.